# Where to add "Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" " inside my httpd.conf?

Tags: apache, xampp, cors

So I read here:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

That I shoudl avoid using .htaccess files since they slow down performance. 
Since I didnt get it to work with .htaccess file so far anyway ([How to enable CORS from .htaccess (inside ZURB Foundation Project)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57522627/how-to-enable-cors-from-htaccess-inside-zurb-foundation-project?noredirect=1#comment101514312_57522627))

I'll give it a try and write it into my httpd.conf

Now I read here the following:
https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled

"To expose the header, you can add the following line inside `<Directory>`, `<Location>`, and `<Files>` sections, or within an .htaccess file.

```
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 </IfModule>"
```

But I have problems understanding what exactly this means ^^ 
I indeed did find the following "section" (if thats what they are referring to) in my httpd.conf, it looks like this:

```
 <Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

And I could also find a file section:

```
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
```

but I couldnt find a location section, and thats making me wonder whether I'm really looking in the right place and whether it would be right to just drop in the above quoted code from the wiki in the directory and file section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowadays you'd normally do this in the apache configuration file where your ServerName is defined (the so-called vhost file). E.g. with ubuntu you would find that file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`. Typically this file will contain the following directives:

```
ServerName your-domain.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/your-website 
<Directory /var/www/html/your-website/>
    ....
</Directory>
```

Just put the cors snippet somewhere in the `Directory` directive where the path matches the `DocumentRoot`. Restart apache2 and it should work.